# Supermartingale that converges almost surely to a constant

Tags: markov-chains, martingales

**Question:** Let $X$ be a Markov chain with countable state space $S$ and a transition matrix $P$. Suppose that $X$ is irreducible and persistent and that $\phi: S \to S$ is bounded function satisfying
$$
\sum_{j \in S}p_{i,j}\phi(j) \le \phi(i) 
$$
for $i \in S$. Show that $\phi$ is a constant function.

**My Attempt** (so far): First, we have that $\phi(X_n)$ is a supermartingale since $E[\phi(X_{n+1})|\mathcal{F}_n] = \sum_{j \in S}p_{X_n,j} \phi(j) \le \phi(X_n)$. By the boundedness of $\phi$ this supermartingale converges almost surely. That is, $\lim_{n \to \infty}\phi(X_n)$ exists.

Also, since this chain is irreducible  we know that the event $\{X_n = i \} \; i.o$ has probability one. However, now I'm not completely sure how to proceed. If anyone has any ideas - I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: You're almost there. Think about he long term behavior of $\phi(X_n)$ if there  were  distinct states $i$ and $j$ with $\phi(i)\not=\phi(j)$.

Comment: I'm guessing that we would have to conclude i = j? I'm not quite sure I understand why.

Comment: The limit $\lim_n\phi(X_n)$ exists. On the one hand, it is equal to $\phi(i)$ because $X_n=i$ infinitely often.  On the other hand, by the same token it is equal to $\phi(j)$.